# Find the length of of a curve of intersection of two surfaces from the origin to a given point

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

I tried going through the steps of this practice problem but I am not getting the answer the textbook says it should be. If someone can tell me where I went wrong that would be great.

I am given the surfaces $x^2=2y$ and $3z=xy$. I need to find the length of their curve of intersection from the origin to the point $(6,18,36)$.

I was able to parametrize that curve and get $r(t) = ti + \frac{t^2}{2}j + \frac{t^3}{6}k$. So the tangent vector of that curve is $r'(t) = i + tj + \frac{t^2}{12}k$. Then the magnitude of the tangent vector is $\sqrt{1^2+t^2+(\frac{t^2}{12})^2}$ = $\sqrt{1+t^2+\frac{t^4}{144}}$

At the origin, $t=0$. At the point $(6,18,36)$, $t=6$. So I figure my answer is:$$\int_0^6{\sqrt{1+t^2+\frac{t^4}{144}}} dt$$

When I plug this integral into any online calculator it comes to ~20.55 but the textbook says the answer is 42. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $r'(t)$ is wrong. The last term should be $t^2/2$, not $t^2/12$

Comment: @Andrei thank you!